# Create two different panes - split the data while splitting a worksheet into two panes vba

Tags: excel, vba

If I split worksheet in Excel, it creates two identical panes. Is there a way to split the data along with it?
I need to have two panes on a worksheet and each needs to have different scroll bar. On left side pane I am taking inputs for project Schedule and on right pane I am showing Gantt chart.
I need to achieve this in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can achieve the effect you seek with panes.  Panes are designed to keep the header row and column on screen as you scroll across and down through the data.

You need to open a second window and then size one to fill the left half of the screen and the other to fill the right half of the screen.

Try the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()

  ' You may have to experiment to get these values correct for your system.
  Const BorderHeight As Single = 30!
  Const BorderWidth As Single = 15!
  Const WindowLeft As Single = 1!
  Const WindowTop As Single = 1!

  Dim WindowHeight As Single
  Dim WindowWidth As Single
  Dim WshtNameLeft As String
  Dim WshtNameRight As String

  WshtNameLeft = "Sheet1"       ' Rename as required
  WshtNameRight = "Sheet2"      ' Rename as required

  ' This demonstrates the macro does not depend on either of
  ' the target worksheets being active.  Delete from final code.
  Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate

 With ActiveWindow
    ' Record full size of window
    WindowHeight = .Height
    WindowWidth = .Width
    ' Open a second window
    .NewWindow
    .WindowState = xlNormal
  End With

  Windows(ActiveWorkbook.Name & ":1").Activate

  With ActiveWindow
    ' Size window to half width while allowing for borders.  Position on left
    .Height = WindowHeight - BorderHeight
    .Left = WindowLeft
    .Top = WindowTop
    .Width = (WindowWidth - BorderWidth) / 2
  End With

  Worksheets(WshtNameLeft).Select

  Windows(ActiveWorkbook.Name & ":2").Activate

  With ActiveWindow
    ' Size window to half width while allowing for borders.  Position on right
    .Height = WindowHeight - BorderHeight
    .Top = WindowTop
    .Width = (WindowWidth - BorderWidth) / 2
    ' "+ 1" is to ensure windows do not overlap
    .Left = WindowLeft + (WindowWidth - BorderWidth) / 2 + 1
  End With

  Worksheets(WshtNameRight).Select

End Sub
```